# CKEditor customize bulleted list style while inserting

Tags: ckeditor

I want to change "list" plugin in CKEditor so when user click on the "Insert Bulleted List" a specific style add to "ul" or "ol" tag like: `list-style-type : square;`.

Any ideas?

**Update:** I know we can use "styles.js" but for User Experience reasons I prefer to do it automatically.

Comment: You can also apply this style from `contents.css`. This is the correct solution if you want to style list this way by default.

Comment: Thanks Reinmar this will change appearance in “CKEditor content area” but I want to set style attribute in source on `ol` and `ul` tags

Comment: @Mojtaba I'd still use css for that. Target it in the page's normal css. Stick a class around it if necessary.

Comment: @NickRice I can do it easily but the "CMS operator" (my customer) doesn't have enough knowledge about css and html. and I don't have enough time to do it for all of my customers.

Comment: @Mojtaba have you looked at the List Style plugin? In its description it claims to let you set the style, such as square etc. See http://ckeditor.com/addon/liststyle

Comment: @NickRice Yes I installed this plugin. It has a context menu to change the style It's very good. Also I should write a Tutorial for my CMS and explain it to my customers. Thank you.